# how to highlight a single bar on select in Plotly Dash

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

I am building a dashboard with Plotly Dash. I have used the slider as input for the bar chart. I would like to use the dropdown to highlight a single country in the bar chart. The connection is shown by the yellow arrows in the picture.

I have used the 'fig1.for_each_trace' to connect it to the dropdown. It does not give an error, but does not what I want.

Can anyone help me out?

This link has put me in this direction:
https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/#conditionally-updating-traces

[image: Dashboard as it should be.]

The callback I have so far:

'''

```
@app.callback(
    [
    Output('barchart-1', 'figure'),
    Output('year-1', 'children')
    ],
    Input('year-slider', 'value'),
    Input('dropdown-country', 'value')
    )
def update_visual(slctd_year, slctd_cntry):
    life = df1[df1['Year'] == slctd_year]
    country = df1[df1['Entity'] == slctd_cntry]

    fig1 = px.bar(
        life,
        x=life['Entity'],
        y=life['Life expectancy'],
        # template='simple white'
    )
    fig1.update_traces(marker_color='rgb(33, 60, 99)',
                       
    )

    fig1.update_layout(
            height= 315,
            margin=dict(l=20, r=30, t=50, b=30),
            plot_bgcolor='rgb(0,0,0,0)',
            legend_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
            paper_bgcolor='rgb(0,0,0,0)',
            font_color='#909090'
        )
    
    fig1.for_each_trace(
        lambda trace: trace.update(marker_color='#9D3469') if trace == country else (),
    )

    return fig1, 'Year: {0}'.format(slctd_year)
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

On the Plotly community forum I got this answer and it works perfectly fine!

```
fig1["data"][0]["marker"]["color"] = ["red" if c == slctd_cntry else "blue" for c in fig1["data"][0]["x"]]
```

This is the link to the topic:
https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-highlight-a-single-bar-on-select-in-plotly-dash/60739/2